# How to get GPT 4 Copilot

Tags: github-copilot, gpt-4

I just signed up for the Github Copilot Business and installed Visual Studio Code for Mac.  I added the GitHub Copilot and the GitHub Copilot Chat extensions.  When I asked it what version it was using it said it was using GPT 3.

I am on the paid-plan (20$ for a month).

How can I get it to use GPT 4?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get it to use GPT 4?

short answer: You can't force copilot to use certain version of GPT model.

But Officially starting **November 30th 2023**, Copilot Chat is powered by GPT-4. [link](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-30-github-copilot-november-30th-update/)

Now both [Copilot for Pull Requests](https://github.blog/2023-03-22-github-copilot-x-the-ai-powered-developer-experience/) and Copilot Chat use GPT-4