# Which one does "Github Copilot Chat" in VSCode use, "Copilot" or "Copilot X"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, github-copilot

Which one does "Github Copilot Chat" plugin in VSCode use, "Copilot" or "Copilot X"?

I'm asking since I want to use the newest one

If it uses just "Copilot"
How can I use "Copilot X" with VSCode plugin?

Comment: _I heard_ Colipot Y knows future data too

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77580213/11107541

Comment: Thank you @starball, it is the same question

Answer (score 1):

Copilot X is not a product, it is just a codename for continuous development of copilot.
hence, if you search for `copilot x` on vscode extentions marketplace nothing shows up.

> This is GitHub Copilot X— **our vision** for the future of AI-powered software development. We are not only adopting OpenAI’s new GPT-4 model, but are introducing chat and voice for Copilot, and bringing Copilot to pull requests, the command line, and docs to answer questions on your projects.
> [link](https://github.blog/2023-03-22-github-copilot-x-the-ai-powered-developer-experience/)